# lua error loading local torch file

Tags: lua, torch

I have a file named `opts.lua`. When i'm trying to load the local module using require `opts` in `main.lua`, it is always searching in `~/torch/install/share/lua/5.1` and getting this error:

> No luarocks module found for opts.

Both `main.lua` and `opts.lua` are in same directory. Please help me in solving this.

Note: I am running the main file in `~/torch/install/bin` using `./th main.lua`

Comment: My bad. It fixed when i placed a path to th in .cshrc and ran it in the main directory of the code.